# Unable to pass the request properly in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have successfully scraped first or second pages of several websites. But while scraping bigbasket.com (an Indian grocery site), even if I am passing _bb_cid to change the city it is not changing the rates of the commodities.

In place of GET request shall I post it in some different way?

Comment: You are getting blocked from bigbasket.com that's why you are not getting updated response. So use proxies to request bigbasket.com and deceive serve.

Comment: No this is not the case. I can access it through the browser.

Comment: Site block bots dude.not Humans

Comment: had you tried it with selenium driver I can share code with you! you can try it.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I have tried selenium. It is giving the results but with default location.

Comment: What you mean by default location. e.g only showing home page only ?

Comment: From Default location I mean the city/area indicated through pincode.